# Find references between a header file and some source file without compiling

Tags: c

I am trying to find out dependencies between some source file and some header file. Can I find them without compiling?
because if I have to go to compilation way, then I can exclude the header and compile but still it may go through successfully if this header is being included by other headers which are included in the source file. So, I can't catch the dependencies.

Also, compilation eats time since this is a huge project containing many sources.

Any suggestions on how to go about this effectively?

Comment: You're trying to determine whether a header file is indirectly included by a source file? Whether a source file makes use of the things declared in a certain header file? If it's not simple to clarify, perhaps add an example of what you'd like to detect.

Comment: You are looking for a tool parsing the sources and building the dependency tree (which is generally off-topic here). Some IDEs can do that. You might find some different tools if you search around. There are no standard tools for this as far as I know

Comment: GCC can do this without compiling, see its option `-M` and friends. This generates rules for the tool make, giving you all dependencies a source has.

Comment: To exclude a header file (without having to worry about whether it's being indirectly included), just wrap the file in a `#if`. In other words, at the top of the file, add the line `#if 0`, and at the end of the file, add `#endif`. As far as the compiler is concerned, that file is empty.

Comment: @aschepler, this header file I am talking about is in a private location and being used by source file of some other module. So, I am trying to find out the dependencies so that I can move the dependencies to some public header which is ideally shared across all the modules.  Is it clear? Please let me know

Comment: @user3386109, actually compilation is not for a specific file rather a whole project which has many modules and compilation is achieved through some variant of make infrastructure. So, if I have to use #if 0 approach for the header and trigger compilation, then I might see failure at other places(other source files) which I am not interested.

Comment: *"find out dependencies between some source file and some header file"* Don't trigger compilation for the entire code base, just compile *"some source file"*.

Comment: @user3386109, If we use #if 0 approach, then that header file can't be included from any other header file as well which might lead to issue right?
Let us take source_file.c, header_file1.h (this is our header file which I am referring to in the question). Assume that, source_file.c includes some other header_file2.h (this includes header_file1.h). Now, if we compile, we will see an error within header_fil2.h as its dependency (header_file1.h) is missing.

Comment: Let's say that source_file.c needs something (X) from header_file2.h and header_file2.h needs something (Y) from header_file1.h. Then two questions need to be answered. Does X depend on Y? Does source_file.c use Y directly? There's no automated tool that's going to sort that out for you. You need to answer those questions yourself. If both answers are "No", then you can use `#if 0` to remove the portion of header_file2.h that depends on Y, and try again.

Comment: @user3386109, Finding X again boils to same problem right? given source file, how to find dependency with some particular header file.

Comment: The compiler error message should give you the line number of a candidate X in header_file2.h. Search for X in source_file.c to see if X is actually needed.